# Heterogeneous queries error using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Stored procedure

```
ALTER    PROCEDURE Proc_DayShift
AS
insert into #Punching_History SELECT * FROM SERVER2.MARS.DBO.TABLE1
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
```

The above stored procedure is showing error as

> Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query
>   semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.

I added the `server1` from `server2` using linked server, when I run the query like this

```
SELECT * FROM SERVER2.MARS.DBO.TABLE1
```

It's executing and showing results.

When I run the query using stored procedure, it is showing this error message.

How to rectify this issue.  what wrong in my query...?

Answer (score 1):

The message mentions two settings.  The first setting, `ansi_nulls`, is remembered from when the stored procedure was created.  Make sure it's on when you run `create procedure`:

```
set ansi_nulls on
go
create procedure YourProc as ...
```

The second setting, `ansi_warnings`, should be enabled on the connection that calls the procedure:

```
set ansi_warnings on 
exec YourProc
```

Or alternatively, set `ansi_warnings` inside the procedure:

```
create procedure YourProc 
as
set ansi_warnings on
...
```

For more information see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx):

> Stored procedures execute with the SET settings specified at execute
>   time except for SET ANSI_NULLS and SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER. Stored
>   procedures specifying SET ANSI_NULLS or SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER use the
>   setting specified at stored procedure creation time. If used inside a
>   stored procedure, any SET setting is ignored.

Comment: I was given inside the store procedure like this create procedure Proc_DayShift @Dates varchar(10) as set ansi_warnings on ...", While executing the store procedure it's showing error as "Must declare the varaibale @Dates"